# Finding duplicate folders and renaming them by prefixing parent folder name in python

Tags: python

I have a folder structure as shown below

[image: Folder_structure]

There are several subfolders with duplicate name,all I wanted is when any duplicate subfolder name is encountered, it should be prefixed with parent folder name.

e.g.
**DIR2>SUBDIR1** should be renamed as **DIR2>DIR2_SUDIR1** , When the folder is renamed to DIR2_SUDIR1 , the file inside this folder should also have the same prefix as its parent folder.
eg. **DIR2>SUBDIR1>subdirtst2.txt** should now become **DIR2>DIR2_SUDIR1>DIR2_subdirtst2.txt**

**What I have done till now ?**

I simply have added all the folder name in a list , after this I am not able to figure out any elegant way to do this task.

```
import os
list_dir=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            path_file = os.path.join(root)
            print(path_file)
            list_dir.append(path_file)
```

Comment: to avoid unnecesary issues, use `os.path.isdir(file)` to find if a file is a folder.

Comment: `os.walk` will recursively visit all directories from the subtree starting at root. Do you intend to rename all the nested directories, or just one level of depth as shown in your image?

Comment: Also, should only duplicate names be replaced in such a manner? Or is it fine to also rename unique names, like say `SUBDIR5` to `DIR2_SUBDIR5`, even though there's only one `SUBDIR5`?

Comment: @TheGamer007 Just one level of depth as shown below, and only duplicate names to renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet should be able to achieve what you desire. I've written it in a way that clearly shows what is being done, so I'm sure there might be tweaks to make it more efficient or elegant.

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

to_be_renamed = set()
for rootdir in next(os.walk(cwd))[1]:
    if to_be_renamed == set():
        to_be_renamed = set(next(os.walk(os.path.join(cwd, rootdir)))[1])
    else:
        to_be_renamed &= set(next(os.walk(os.path.join(cwd, rootdir)))[1])

for rootdir in next(os.walk(cwd))[1]:
    subdirs = next(os.walk(os.path.join(cwd, rootdir)))[1]
    for s in subdirs:
        if s in to_be_renamed:
            srcpath = os.path.join(cwd, rootdir, s)
            dstpath = os.path.join(cwd, rootdir, rootdir+'_'+s)
            # First rename files
            for f in next(os.walk(srcpath))[2]:
                os.rename(os.path.join(srcpath, f), os.path.join(srcpath, rootdir+'_'+f))
            # Now rename dir
            os.rename(srcpath, dstpath)
            print('Renamed', s, 'and files')
```

Here, `cwd` stores the path to the dir that contains DIR1, DIR2 and DIR3. The first loop checks all immediate subdirectories of these 'root directories'  and creates a set of duplicated subdirectory names by repeatedly taking their intersection (`&`).

Then it runs another loop, checks if the subdirectory is to be renamed and finally uses the `os.rename` function to rename it and all the files it contains.

`os.walk()` returns a 3-tuple with path to the directory, the directories in it, and the files in it, at each step. It 'walks' the tree in either a top-down or bottom-up manner, and doesn't stop at one iteration.

So, the built-in `next()` method is used to generate the first result (that of the current dir), after which either `[1]` or `[2]` is used to get directories and files respectively.

If you want to rename not just files, but all items in the subdirectories being renamed, then replace `next(os.walk(srcpath))[2]` with `os.listdir(srcpath)`. This list contains both files and directories.

**NOTE:** The reason I'm computing the list of duplicated names first in a separate loop is so that the first occurrence is not left unchanged. Renaming in the same loop will miss that first one.

Comment: The above code works perfectly fine!!  however i also need to rename file of the impacted folder. Please see my edit in question.

Comment: In your edited image, the names of the txt files are not the same. So are all files in the renamed directories to be appended with the same prefix, or is there some other condition involved? The more conditions you add, the more complicated the code will get obviously.

Comment: all the files in the renamed directories to be appended with same prefix!!